# Parse specific strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I' ve got this string:

DealerCode = [MAZ3].AccountID:[4340].StartDate=[2015-06-01]

```
select parsename('DealerCode = [MAZ3].AccountID:[4340].StartDate=[2015-06-01]', 1)
```

and so on gives me null. How should i change my query to get values between dots?

Comment: Search here for split functions ;).

Comment: @lgO , Do you only want 'AccountID:[4340]' to be returned or all 3 segments?

Comment: I wan to get
DealerCode = [MAZ3] AccountID:[4340] StartDate=[2015-06-01] all 3 values apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @param = 'DealerCode = [MAZ3].AccountID:[4340].StartDate=[2015-06-01]'

SELECT 
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS CVS  
FROM  
(
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@param, '.', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS 
) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: Wow that was creative. Sorry for useless comment, but I felt the urge to applaud.